# In my mySQL Database I got pathes to images, how can I display them on my Site?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I a beginner and this is only for learning.
My goal is to display the images of my database with the other content in the same row on my HTML.

This is the JS code in my HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            "use strict";
            
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            callArticles();
        });
         
        </script>
```

This is from my Ajax file

```
"use strict";

let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      

        let response = this.responseText;
        let dbContent = document.getElementById('dbContent');
        dbContent.innerHTML = response;
    }
}

function callArticles() {
    "use strict";

    let param = 'PHP/getBikes.php';

    ajax.open("GET", param);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
    ajax.send();
}
```

And this is my PHP code

```
<?php

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'bikes';

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if($con->connect_error){
    die("cannot connect to database: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bike"; 
$result = $con->query($sql);

$data = array();


if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
        
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
$con->close();
?>
```

I didn't find anything that helped me

Comment: Your response from php is json. You need to parse it to a js variable, then use JS to loop through the results and make some html to format the data,  including `<img` tags for the images. Then set the html string as the dbContent.innerHTML

Comment: Please post example output from `json_encode($data);`

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a database that looks like this

```
id  name    image_path
1   Item 1  /images/item1.jpg
2   Item 2  /images/item2.jpg
3   Item 3  /images/item3.jpg
```

You need to parse the json - for example like this

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const dbContent = document.getElementById('dbContent');
  const process = (data) => dbContent.innerHTML = data.map(({image_path}) => `<img src="${image_path}" />`).join('');

  /*
  fetch('PHP/getBikes.php')
    .then(response => reponse.json())
    .then(data => process(data))
  */
  process(data); // test, remove this when you uncomment the fetch
});
```

```html
<div id="dbContent"></div>



<script>
// test data returned from fetch

data = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Item 1",
    "image_path": "/images/item1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Item 2",
    "image_path": "/images/item2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Item 3",
    "image_path": "/images/item3.jpg"
  }
]
</script>
```